# passing data using delegate in window form c# (subscribe and unsubscribe)

Tags: c#, delegates, subscribe, unsubscribe

I have to pass data using the collection for two objects ( email, mobile). If I click the button subscriber or unsubscribe, the values that I enter should be stored and showed to another form if I click publish button. However, I require to use 'delegate' for this task.

This is the form that I handle value I entered

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Q1
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {

        // declare delegate
        public delegate void PublishMessageDel(ArrayList publist);

        public PublishMessageDel publist = null;

        public void PublishMessage(ArrayList subscribers)
        {
            publist.Invoke(subscribers);
        }

        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void btnBackToMain_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            // back to first form when the buttom is clicked
            this.Hide();
            Form1 mainWindow = new Form1();
            mainWindow.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }

        private void txtEmailTo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                IsEmailFormMatch();
            }
            else if (!ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = false;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = false;

            }

        }

        private void txtTextTo_Validating(object sender, CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if (ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                IsMobileFormMatch();
            }
            else if (!ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = false;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = false;

            }

        }


        // check valid email and button visibility
        public void IsEmailFormMatch()
        {
            string emailForm = (@"^([\w-\.]+)@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.)|(([\w-]+\.)+))([a-zA-Z]{2,4}|[0-9]{1,3})(\]?)$");

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtEmailTo.Text, emailForm))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Email");
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = false;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = true;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        // check valid mobile and button visibility
        public void IsMobileFormMatch()
        {
            string mobileForm = (@"\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}");

            if (!Regex.IsMatch(txtTextTo.Text, mobileForm))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Invalid Phone Number");
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = false;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = false;
            }
            else
            {
                btnSubscribe.Enabled = true;
                btnUnsubscribe.Enabled = true;
            }
        }

        private void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList subscribers = new ArrayList();

            if (ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Add(txtEmailTo.Text);
            }
            else if (ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Add(txtTextTo.Text);                
            }

            foreach (ArrayList list in subscribers)
            {
                PublishMessage(list);
            }
        }

        private void btnUnsubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList subscribers = new ArrayList();

            if (ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Remove(txtEmailTo.Text);

            }
            else if (ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Remove(txtTextTo.Text);
            }

        }

    }
}
```

I think this part has a problem.

```
private void btnSubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList subscribers = new ArrayList();

            if (ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Add(txtEmailTo.Text);
            }
            else if (ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Add(txtTextTo.Text);                
            }

            foreach (ArrayList list in subscribers)
            {
                PublishMessage(list);
            }
        }

        private void btnUnsubscribe_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList subscribers = new ArrayList();

            if (ckbEmailTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Remove(txtEmailTo.Text);

            }
            else if (ckbTextTo.Checked)
            {
                subscribers.Remove(txtTextTo.Text);
            }

        }
```

This is the form if I click publish button, the textbox should have to show me the values that subscribed in the previous form.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Q1
{
    public partial class Form3 : Form
    {
        Form2 fm2;
        public Form3()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            
        }

        private void btnBackToMain3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.Hide();
            Form1 mainWindow = new Form1();
            mainWindow.ShowDialog();
            this.Close();
        }

        // change button visibility when the textbox is empty or not
        public void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 fm2 = new Form2();

            var value = fm2.publist += Subscribe;
            txtSubscribers.Text += value;
            //fm2.PublishMessage();

        }

        public void Subscribe(ArrayList list)
        {
            ArrayList subscribers = list;
            txtSubscribers.Text += subscribers.ToString();
        }

        
    }
}
```

I think I used delegate not properly and stuck to link with it..

Comment: I don't see any _question_ in your question. Please fix the post so that it includes a proper [mcve], a clear description of what the code does, how that's different from what you want, and what _specifically_ you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

This is [using delegates microsoft guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/using-delegates). 
"A delegate is a type that safely encapsulates a method, similar to a function pointer in C and C++. Unlike C function pointers, delegates are object-oriented, type safe, and secure. The type of a delegate is defined by the name of the delegate."

So, before invoking `arrSubscribers.Invoke(list);` you should make a method in `Form3` which takes the signature of your delegate(you receive as a parameter your `ArrayList arrSubscribers`) and add the reference to `fm2.arrSubscribers`.

> public void YourMethod(ArrayList arrSubscribers) 
> {
> // Your code with subscribers here 
> }

`fm2.arrSubscribers = YourMethod;` or `fm2.arrSubscribers += YourMethod;` 
Example:

```
    private ArrayList subscribers;
    public Form2(Form1 form)

    {
        InitializeComponent();
        form.arrSubscribers = MyMethod;
    }

    public void MyMethod(ArrayList list)
    {
        subscribers = list;
    }

    private void Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var query = from string item in subscribers
                    select item;
        label1.Text = string.Join(", ", query);
    }
```

Comment: After defining the method to invoke the delegate in Form3, I have to call the method in `btnPublish` button. But I how can call the ArrayList from From 2?
`private void btnPublish_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
   Subscribe();
  }

  public void Subscribe(ArrayList arrSubscribers)
  {
   fm2.arrSubscribers += Subscribe;
  }
`

Comment: I have just added example to my answer. Also take into account that you should check if your delegate is not null before calling  `arrSubscribers.Invoke(list);`

Comment: I edit `delegate`, `btnSubscribe` parts, but not sure how can I link them to Form3 .. I edit last part of it. Could you check it?

Comment: Could you describe your task in details? For which reason you must use delegate? Maybe you should use some service to store your subscribers and pass it to both forms?

Comment: [Quick example] (https://gitlab.com/SerhiiMahera/delegate-win-forms)

Comment: I have to use a delegate to store them.. 
Tasks: When Subscribe button is clicked, an object of SendViaEmail or/and an object of
SendViaMobile is/are instantiated, and should be added to the corresponding collection(s) if the email or/and mobile has/have not been
subscribed before; finish the subscription